# How to load data into blaze from hive2

Tags: python, hive, sqlalchemy, impala, blaze

All,

I am attempting to load data into blaze from a hive2 thrift server. I would like to do some analysis similar to what is posted [here](http://blaze.pydata.org/blog/2015/09/16/reddit-impala/). Here is my current process.

```
import blaze as bz
import sqlalchemy
import impala

conn = connect(host='myhost.url.com', port=10000, database='mydb', user='hive', auth_mechanism='PLAIN')
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('hive://', creator=conn) 
data = bz.data(engine)
```

I am able to make the connection and generate the engine, but when I run bz.data it fails with the error

```
 TypeError: 'HiveServer2Connection' object is not callable
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Answer**

```
from pyhive import import hive
import sqlalchemy
from impala.dbapi import import connect


def conn():                                               
    return connect(host='myhost.com', port=10000, database='database',        user='username', auth_mechanism='PLAIN')

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('hive://', creator=conn)


#Workaround
import blaze as bz


data = bz.data(engine)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from pyhive import import hive
import sqlalchemy
from impala.dbapi import import connect


def conn():                                               
    return connect(host='myhost.com', port=10000, database='database', user='username', auth_mechanism='PLAIN')

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('hive://', creator=conn)


#Workaround
import blaze as bz


data = bz.data(engine)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue when using impyla to connect to Impala with SQLAlchemy.  Making conn a function instead of assigning it to a variable worked.